# C++ bindings (deprecated)

Tags: c++, ubuntu, mpi

I am using Ubuntu 18.04. I am trying to install MPI now i get these errors,Please help me.
Open MPI configuration:

```
-----------------------
Version: 4.0.2
Build MPI C bindings: yes
Build MPI C++ bindings (deprecated): no
Build MPI Fortran bindings: mpif.h, use mpi, use mpi_f08
MPI Build Java bindings (experimental): no
Build Open SHMEM support: false (no spml)
Debug build: no
Platform file: (none)
```

Comment: Are you sure that those are errors?

Comment: I am following a tutorial and these are extra outputs. c++ bindings (deprecated):no why it's no?

Comment: make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'install-exec-am
 /bin/mkdir -p '/openmpi/share/openmpi/amca-param-sets'
/bin/mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/openmpi’: Permission denied
Makefile:1789: recipe for target 'install-dist_amca_paramDATA' failed
make[2]: *** [install-dist_amca_paramDATA] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/bilal/openmpi/openmpi-4.0.2/contrib'
Makefile:1880: recipe for target 'install-am' failed

Comment: Because c++ bindings were deprecated and then removed from the MPI standard a decade ago. Though you can rebuild Open MPI with c++ bindings, I can only encourage you to modernize your code, either with plain C bindings or other third party c++ bindings such as Boost.MPI or Elementals.

Comment: make[1]: *** [install-am] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/bilal/openmpi/openmpi-4.0.2/contrib'
Makefile:1879: recipe for target 'install-recursive' failed
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1

Comment: @Gilles Gouaillardet .How can I build C bindings?

Comment: C bindings are always built.

Comment: Then how can i solve this issue?

Comment: Which issue? The permission error has nothing to do with which MPI bindings you are building.

Comment: Sir when i use next command "make install". it's not installing.

Comment: /bin/mkdir -p '/openmpi/share/openmpi/amca-param-sets'
/bin/mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/openmpi’: Permission denied
Makefile:1789: recipe for target 'install-dist_amca_paramDATA' failed
make[2]: *** [install-dist_amca_paramDATA] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/bilal/openmpi/openmpi-4.0.2/contrib'
Makefile:1880: recipe for target 'install-am' failed
make[1]: *** [install-am] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/bilal/openmpi/openmpi-4.0.2/contrib'
Makefile:1879: recipe for target 'install-recursive' failed
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1

Comment: Either install in an other location or ensure you have the right permissions.

Comment: @ Gilles Gouaillardet. Thanks a lot. ok I am tyring.

Comment: @ Gilles Gouaillardet, Sir How I should set MPI_DIR?

Comment: @ Gilles Gouaillardet

Comment: Running configuration script for thorn MPI:
MPI selected, but MPI_DIR is not set. Computing settings...
Found MPI compiler wrapper at /usr/bin/mpic++!
Successfully configured MPI.
Finished running configuration script for thorn MPI.

Comment: Take a deep breath and ask one question at a time while providing all information to answer it. This is the third issue in the same question and it looks like it came from nowhere since you did not provide any context.

Comment: @ Gilles Gouaillardet, Sir how I should set MPI_DIR?

Answer (score 0):

I found one available option in `configure` file of `openmpi`.

> You can add the option `--enable-mpi-cxx` to when running `./configure` to enable the CXX binding of `openmpi`, which is disabled by default